# Dplyr Attempt to query lazy column with non-natural slicing index

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following code:

```
df %>% group_by(Sku, ProductId) %>% 
    summarise(SkuRank = dense_rank(Sku)) %>% 
    arrange(desc(SkuRank))
```

It fails with

> Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: Attempt to
>   query lazy column with non-natural slicing index.

It's a while since I've used R but I don't remember ever seeing that error before. Google is not much help. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: I think your issue is you are grouping by the same column you are ranking.  Remove `Sku` from `group_by` and try again

Comment: @Dave Gruenewald Your right! `df %>% group_by(Sku, ProductId) %>% summarise() %>% mutate(Rank = dense_rank(Sku)) %>% filter(Rank > 1)` worked! Post an answer, the error message is really difficult to google so someone might have same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a variable is already taken as a `grouping variable` in `group_by`, a summary cannot be calculated using that variable using `summarise`. Two options:

1. Should not be attempted.
2. Use `ungroup` prior to using `summarise`.